# Por que é que «duro», «teso» e «liso» significam sem dinheiro?

Tags: etimologia

[***Duro***](http://www.aulete.com.br/duro) e [***liso***](http://www.aulete.com.br/liso) no Brasil e [***teso***](http://www.aulete.com.br/teso) em todo o lado significa sem dinheiro. Mas não consigo ver porquê.

*Duro* e *teso* partilham muitos dos seu significados, como *rijo, valente*. Mas não vejo o que é que isto tenha que ver com não ter dinheiro.

Então aqui fica a pergunta: como é que estas palavras vieram a significar sem dinheiro. E, já agora, quando é que isso aconteceu.

Comment: *Duro* e *teso* me lembram ["hard up"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard%20up) no inglês, e *liso* ["pelado"](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/pelado) no espanhol, mas não conheço a etimologia de nenhum deles. (E bem que pode ser coincidência.)

Comment: @DanGetz *Hard up* antes de siginificar em dificuldades, sem dinheiro, 1821, era [uma expressão náutica, relativa à condução do navio](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hard+up). Será que vem daí? Leme duro, teso? *Pelado* sugere-me, *nu, despido*, mas não creio que liso tenha esse significaddo.

Comment: pão duro é alguém que não abre a mão para pagar nada. talvez estar duro tenha a ver com não poder abrir a mão por não ter dinheiro.

Answer (score 4):

Tal como está explicado [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/estar-teso-como-um/21018), a expressão estar *teso* é uma redução da expressão *estar teso como um carapau*, isto é, sem vida, inerte. Por associação, pode-se inferir que, como sem dinheiro nada se pode fazer, fica-se sem vida, inerte, *teso*.

Do mesmo modo, se pode inferir a explicação para as expressões *duro* e *liso*, muito utilizadas no Brasil.

Comment: +1 pelo achado interessante, mas a tua leitura é precipitada. A hipótese *teso como um carapau > morto > sem dinheiro* é apresentada como mera especulação; a tua resposta dá outra ideia. Não se diz que *teso* é redução de *teso como carapau*. Podia ser o contrário: *teso como carapau* ser extensão de *teso*. Se *teso como carapau* significar *morto*, é por a pessoa morta ficar hirta, tesa; comparar com carapau ajuda mais se este for vivo; peixe morto fica mole (o artigo está um bocado baralhado neste aspeto). Este raciocínio pode aplicar-se a *duro*, mas não a *liso*. Liso significa morto?

Comment: De acordo com a tradução para fracês de *estar liso*, feita pelo [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Traduzir/FR/estar+liso+%5Bsem+dinheiro%5D), não tem associação com estar morto mas sim com estar na rua, no pavimento.

Metaforicamente falando, tornamo-nos um com a rua e como a rua é lisa, tornamo-nos igualmente lisos.

Comment: O Priberam simplesmente apresenta um expressão idiomática francesa, [être sur le pavé](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/9377), que é usada com um significado próximo de *estar liso*, mas isso não significa na minha opinião que o *liso* na nossa expressão alguma vez tivesse que ver com *rua*. Do mesmo modo *chover a cântaros* é equivalente a *raining cats and dogs*, mas isso não significa que cântaros tenham que ver com cães ou gatos.

Comment: Correcto, concordo plenamente com a segunda observação. Contudo, claramente que há étimos partilhados entre várias palavras portuguesas e francesas, o que, neste caso e na minha opinião, remete à comparação da expressão nas duas línguas. Mas a verdade é que não encontrei nenhuma fonte que ateste que ao estarmos sem dinheiro estamos *lisos*.